# Infinite scroll not working on home page cms

Tags: magento-1.7

I am a newbie to magento, I installed [Strategery InfiniteScroll 2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strategery-infinitescroll-2-9213.html) for infinite scrolling of products. It works properly in inner pages. It is not working in home page.

When i viewed the home page source code the jquery files are not included in home page(cms).
How can i include an extensions jquery files on home page. The jquery.latest.min.js also not included in home page. How can i include this on home page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this on your home page only, then open your **home page in admin panel under CMS->Pages**

in **Layout Update XML** field under **Design** Tab add the following:

```
    <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem" ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>jquery/jquery.latest.min.js</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem" ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>jquery/infinitescroll2/jquery.infinitescroll.js</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem" ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>jquery/infinitescroll2/behaviors/infinitescroll-magento.js</name>
    </action>
    </reference>
```

> Note:
>
> Remember this will work only if products on your home page are
>   paginated.

Comment: glad that works :)