# Infinity scroll not working on homepage

Tags: javascript, ajax, products

My design requirement is to show latest products on homepage with infinite scroll. During my search for the solution, i checked [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/infinite-scroll-not-working-on-home-page-cms) so i first of all installed Strategy Infinity scroll, and then showed products on homepage with pagination following [this tutorial](http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/). This seem not to be working.

When i showed products on homepage with pagination, there doesn't appear the ajax loader, indicating that on homepage infinite scroll plugin isn't taking any effect. I've carefully added in Layout Update XML field under Design Tab with the following:

```
  <reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem" ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled">
    <type>js</type>
    <name>jquery/jquery.latest.min.js</name>
  </action>
  <action method="addItem" ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled">
    <type>js</type>
    <name>jquery/infinitescroll2/jquery.infinitescroll.js</name>
  </action>
  <action method="addItem" ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled">
    <type>js</type>
    <name>jquery/infinitescroll2/behaviors/infinitescroll-magento.js</name>
  </action>
  </reference>
```

But still these javascript files were not included in homepage's source codes. Which indicate that this condition didn't met (only on homepage):

```
ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled"
```

However when I deleted this condition in xml to include the files anyway, the js files got included, but desired functionality didn't occur.

Can someone point out what could be the problem.

Comment: why you had deleted the previous question? can you put the code from `infinitescroll-magento.js` if its not too long

Comment: I edited the previous question too much that whole scope of it changed. That's why deleted that. There is no such file infinitescroll-magento,js. There file included are jquery.infinitescroll.js and jquery.infinitescroll.min.js

Comment: there would be a script which will initiate the `infinitescroll js`.

Comment: Hmm... where could i look for that?

Comment: the module supposed to have a template file or there could be a js file. without that it might not make sense that your scroll will work.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked it. It was right under js/infinitescroll2/behaviors folder. I've uploaded it [here for you](http://demo.webdezyner.com/infinitescroll-magento.js)

Comment: BTW another strange javascript error is occuring on category page. I've posted it as a [seperate question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713794/javascript-unrecognized-expression-error). There are no errors on homepage however.

Comment: it could not help in debug. can you give the link from where you had installed this module?

Comment: I went to this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strategery-infinitescroll.html) and got extension key for magento connect 2, and then from admin panel's System->Magento Connect->Magento Connect Manager entered that key and it installed that for me.

Comment: Thanks for painstakingly helping me on this. If I upload it on server, will it help you then to debug the issue?

Comment: i can not give the guarantee but look forward for it in my local installation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks bro. Let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. I'd installed this module in my local and it was working perfectly. the problem may be in the `jquery` - `css` selectors. have you made changes in configuration group named **Selectors** under **System > Configuration > Infinity Scroll**?

Comment: I checked the selectors, on the code generated on homepage the selectors are the same, so i don't know if that should be the problem. Also, I don't understand why the check  `ifconfig="infinitescroll2/general/enabled"` is returning false on homepage.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: No Bro. Still stuck!

Comment: have you got it working on category pages? I'd checked the module and it is working. I'd not tested it on homepage due to one of my module conflict. maybe there's any module which will causing problem with this

Comment: Yes it seems to work on category pages. But on homepage it isn't working.

Comment: @anwartheravian could post the complete layout.xml I wonder if the js is not added via the layout to the cms pages

Answer (score 1):

The module [infinite scroll](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strategery-infinitescroll.html) seems to be developed for

1. Grid/List mode
2. Layer model
3. Search
4. Advance Search

As you can see in you system > config > Infinite Scroll > Instances(group).
In order to meet your expectation for the homepage you may need to extend this module for the home page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to make it work on a homepage was to add this to Layout Update XML in the Design tab for the individual CMS page.  It's taken from the strategery-infinitescroll.xml page:

```
 <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="infinitescroll/init" name="infinitescroll_init">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>strategery/infinitescroll/init.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Also, if you are trying to infinite load a product list on a cms page you also need to follow the instructions shown here (David Perlman's answer):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555157/show-pagination-links-for-product-list-on-a-magento-cms-page/7916665#7916665